# how to grep for c:\

Tags: shell, grep, quoting, cygwin

I'm using cygwin's grep to find all instances of hardcoded paths on c drive.
doing:

```
grep -r "c:\\" .
```

gives `grep: trailing backslash`

Does anybody know how I can do this?

Comment: Just for a chance, try grep -r "c:[\\]" .

Comment: Thanks for response! it gives no error but it doesn't match anything...

Comment: EDIT - scratch that. Sorry. That does work too - the lack of matching was my error. Thanks @Serge

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your error is because you are using double quotes (`"`), which allow the contents to be interpreted by the shell before it gets to `grep`.

Try `grep -r 'c:\\' .` instead.

```
echo 'c:\' > test
ire@localhost$ cat test
c:\
ire@localhost$ grep -r 'c:\\' test
c:\
```

*Explanation*: `\` has a special meaning, both to the shell and to grep. It's used as an escape character, to allow the next character to be interpreted literally.

When you do `grep "c:\\"`, the shell picks up the content, converts it to the literal string `c:\`, and passes that to `grep`. `grep` sees the single backslash, and interprets it as an escape character. But there's no character following the `\` to escape! So, quite reasonably it complains.

Using single quotes (`'`) protects the content from the shell. But you still need two slashes, because you need to tell `grep` this is a literal backslash you are wanting to search for.

Alternatively, you could have done:

```
grep -rF 'C:\' .
```

or

```
grep -rF "C:\\" .
```

The `-F` option to grep (formerly known as the `fgrep` command) tells `grep` to look for *fixed strings*, and therefore there's nothing to escape and the backslash is not special to `grep` (but still is for the shell inside double quotes).

Comment: Alternatively, do `grep -r "c:\\\\"` so grep will see `c:\\ ` as its input string (single quotes are a better method)

Comment: `grep -F` (`fgrep`) seems the most "fitting" choice for this particular case, since `C:\` is intended as a literal string.

Answer (score 0):

Or just use `"c:/"` instead (which also works under Windows).